# Does vertica flex tables has projections?

Tags: vertica, flextable

I'm using vertica flex tables i want to know how to apply projections on flex table

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean for columns that you've materialized?

Comment: yes,how to improve the performance of flex tables ?

Answer (score 0):

A freshly created flex table looks like this when you export its definition:

```
    CREATE FLEX TABLE public.teas
    (

    );


    CREATE PROJECTION public.teas_super /*+basename(teas),createtype(P)*/ 
    (
     __identity__,
     __raw__
    )
    AS
     SELECT teas.__identity__,
            teas.__raw__
     FROM public.teas
     ORDER BY teas.__identity__
    SEGMENTED BY hash(teas.__identity__) ALL NODES OFFSET 0;
```

No columns but the two hidden ones `__identity__`, which is an int, and `__raw__`, which is a long varbinary (130000).

Not much point in creating different projections, here.

You can load into the flex table, and then materialise a few columns that you find especially interesting in a flex table.

Then, they will appear in the output of an `export_objects()`, and you will be able to create projections for these.

Hope this helps ..
Marco